# Percent of Total Using a Date Column of Various Dates

Tags: dax, percentage

I'm brand new to DAX & SQL and have found a potential answer to my question, but do not fully understand it.  (Percent of Total column w/Filter - Answer by: Alexis Olson).  I'm trying to calculate a % of a monthly total, for various sale types, as of a report date.  In Excel, one can reference a cell to carry through in a formula.  (=SUMIF($F$2:$F$3870,***F2***,$D$2:$D$3870).  The **F2** field refers to the ReportDate in the Excel file.  Is there way to do this in DAX with a column called ReportDate?  (This column contains the same dates.)

Answer (score 0):

In PowerBI DAX you can use measure, which are similar to Excel formula. You can use something like this:

```
sumif = CALCULATE(SUM('TableName'[ColumnD]),'TableName'[ColumnF] = SELECTEDValue('TableName'[ColumnF]))
```

You can check [this link](https://www.learndax.com/sumif-power-bi-equivalent-in-dax-with-simple-examples/) for more examples